# Rails Validation on presence of two or more entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I've got two columns by name,

**product_available_count (***integer***) and product_available_on (***date***)**.

I need to perform a model level validation on these columns.

The validation should check that if **product_required** is true then **either** of fields should be populated.

When a Product Manager fill in the catalogue, we need to perform a **model level validation** that checks that he should fill in either of the fields.

Suggest me any elegant way of writing a custom validation for my requirement.

I've tried this approach

```
validates :product_available_count_or_product_available_on if product_required?

def product_available_count_or_product_available_on
  //logic ???
end
```

Is Custom validation the only way forward to my requirement. Can I use Proc or any other approach to write a better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Custom validation is best approach for this kind of problem

```
validate :product_available_count_or_product_available_on if product_required?

def product_available_count_or_product_available_on
  if [product_available_count, product_available_on].compact.blank.size == 0
    errors[:base] << ("Please select alteast one.")
  end
end
```

but if you really donot want to write custom validation then try this

```
validates :product_available_count, :presence => { :if =>  product_required? && product_available_on.blank? }
validates :product_available_on, :presence => { :if =>  product_required? && product_available_count.blank? }
```

Comment: Was looking for the second solution.